# Access to network files under \\directory

Tags: networking

I was doing Start - Run - '\\myfiles' under Windows XP and had access to some file directories over my network.

I dont know how to do the same thing under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `smb://` instead of `\\` in the nautilus address line.

You can specifiy a username and a password, too. Like that: `smb://username:password@hostname/`. If you don't, nautilus will automatically ask you for it.

---

You can use all other supported protocols in the same way:

- `smb://username:password@hostname/` for Samba
- `ftp://username:password@hostname/` for FTP
- `sftp://username:password@hostname/` for FTP over SSH (also `ssh://` )
- `dav://username:password@hostname/`for WebDAV
- `davs://username:password@hostname/` for encrypted WebDAV

Comment: This is the right answer I think however it still does not work. I guess I have to contact my network administrator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus (the file browser), you should be able to go to Network in the side pane. That should bring up a list of network resources the computer can see; myfiles should be listed there.