# Access a network folder in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, xfce4-terminal

I used to access files by typing  `\\\fileserver2` in run command in windows. How do I access them in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I tried using `ftp://fileserver2` in terminal but it said there is no such directory.

I am new to Linux so I have no idea. I followed the answer to "[Access to network files under \\directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65276/access-to-network-files-under-directory)" but it didn't work.

Comment: no i used smb://fileserver2 but it dint work either.

Comment: What's the output of `ping fileserver2`? Through which protocol(s) does it grant file access? FTP? SFTP? SMB/CIFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to mount your FTP server so you can access it via GUI, do the following** (this is probably the most convenient solution):

Install curlftpfs. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install curlftpfs
```

Create the directory you want to mount your FTP server to, for example

```
mkdir /home/username/fileserver2
```

Then mount it with

```
curlftpfs username:password@fileserver2 /path/to/your/created/folder -o allow_other,disable_eprt
```

Or if you want a SSL/TLS encrypted connection

```
curlftpfs username:password@fileserver2 /path/to/your/created/folder -o allow_other,disable_eprt,tlsv1
```

If you dont need it anymore, use

```
fusermount -u /path/to/your/created/folder
```

to unmount it.

**Alternatives:**

- Use a FTP client like FileZilla
- Use the terminal: `sudo apt-get install ftp` and then `ftp servername`. To learn how to use it look at the manpage via `man ftp`